# Approximate solution of $H(x)=(x!)^k$

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, approximation, factorial

In the frame of some physics work, I have to solve for $x$ the equation
$$H(x)=(x!)^k$$ where $H(x)$ is the hyperfactorial function and $k$ a postive real number which can be very large.

I wrote it as
$$f(x)=k \qquad \text{where} \qquad f(x)=\frac{\log (H(x))}{\log (x!)}$$ From  a numerical point of view, the problem is not difficult since $f(x)$ is "almost" a linear function of $x$. Some information at two points
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \, f(x)=\frac{\log (2 \pi )-3}{2 (\gamma -1)}\approx 1.37437$$ $$\lim_{x\to 1} \, f'(x)=\frac{42+12 (\gamma -3) \gamma -3 \pi ^2+\left(\pi ^2-6\right) \log (2 \pi )}{24
   (\gamma -1)^2}\approx 0.634375$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \, f''(x)\approx -0.021330$$ while
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \, f(x)=\infty \qquad \lim_{x\to \infty} \, f'(x)=\frac 12\qquad \lim_{x\to \infty} \,f^{(n)}(x)=0\quad \forall n>1$$ I hope that this is sufficient to justify the quasi-linearity of $f(x)$.

Concerning the unsigned curvature, $\kappa(0)\approx 0.012843$ and $\kappa(x)$ decreases very fast $(\kappa(10)\approx 0.001240, \kappa(100)\approx 0.000062)$.

Expanding $f(x)$ for infinite values of x
$$f(x)=\frac{(2 \log (x)-1)x}{4( \log (x)-1)}+\frac{\log (x) (2 \log (x)-3-2 \log (2 \pi ))+\log (2 \pi )}{8 (\log (x)-1)^2}+\cdots$$ For any $x$, the second term is very small compared to the first (the maximum value of their ratio is $0.00324$ at $x \sim 43$. So, ignoring it, the equation becomes
$$\frac{(2 \log (x)-1)x}{4( \log (x)-1)}=k$$  and
$$\frac{f(x)}{\frac{(2 \log (x)-1)x}{4( \log (x)-1)}  }=1+\frac{2 \log ^2(x)-\log \left(\frac{4 }{3}\pi ^2\right) \log (x)+\log (2 \pi )}{2 x \left(2 \log
   ^2(x)-3 \log (x)+1\right)}+\cdots$$

If $x$ is really large, a very crude estimate could be $x_0=2k$. This is not too bad for Newton method (I give below the iterates for $k=1234$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2468.000000 \\
 1 & 2297.505131 \\
 2 & 2297.548546
\end{array}
\right)$$ while is exact solution of the complete equation should be $2297.186319$.

To have a better approximation, letting $x=e^y$, we should have
$$e^{-y}=\frac 1{2k}\frac{ y-\frac12}{ y-1}$$ the solution of which being given in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$); this is nice to know but not very practical.

> > Just for the art for art's sake, is there any way to generate some better estimates ?

Any idea or suggestion would really be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My post being already too long, I prefer to add an answer to it rather than to edit it.*

I started with a different approach considering instead that I am looking for the zero of function
$$g(x)=\log (H(x))-k \log (x!)$$ Using $x_0=2k$, the first iterate of Newton method is given by
$$x_1=2k-\frac{2 \log (H(2 k))-2 k \log ((2k)!)}{2 \log ((2k)!)+4
   k-2 k \psi(2 k+1)+1-\log (2 \pi )}$$ Now, using expansion for large values of $k$, I end with
$$\color{blue}{x_1^*= 2 k-\frac{2 k+\log (2 k)-\log (2 \pi )}{2
   \log (2 k)}+\frac{2 \log (2 k)+1}{4 \log ^2(2 k)}}$$

For the test example $(k=1234)$, this gives $x_1=2309.706772$, $x_1^*=2309.706724$ while the exact solution is $2297.186319$.

From a numerical point of view, it is better to consider $g(x)$ rather than $f(x)$ since, for any of the proposed guesses $x_*$ $f(x_*) \, f''(x_*) <0$ means that, by Darboux theorem, we should have one overshoot of the solution while $g(x_*) \, g''(x_*) <0$ guarantees no overshoot at all.

**Update**

Doing the same work with the approximating function mentioned in the post

$$h(x)=(2 \log (x)-1)x-{4k( \log (x)-1)}$$ which is much simpler to handle, using high order methods, I obtained things such
$$x_2=2k \frac{\sum_{i=1}^9 a_i t^i}{\sum_{i=1}^9 b_i t^i} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t={\log(2k)}$$

The $a_i$'s correspond to the sequence
$$\{667,-111648,-156240,1348032,803040,-4435200,564480,4515840,-3225600,645120\}$$

and the $b_i$'s to
$$\{-4509,-78720,69552,1099392,-272160,-3548160,1693440,3225600,-2903040,645120\} $$

From those, truncated series could easily be obtained by long division; for example
$$x_2=2k\left(1-\frac{1}{2 t}-\frac{1}{4 t^2}-\frac{3}{8 t^3}-\frac{1}{2 t^4}-\frac{77}{96t^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)\right)$$

Using the terms of the present table, for the test case we should get $x_2=2297.54854638212$ while the solution of $h(x)=0$ is  $2297.54854638189$ and the exact solution of $g(x)=0$ is $2297.186319$.

Comment: @robjohn; Any idea to get a good approximation of $y$ solution of $e^{-y}=\frac 1{2k}\frac{ y-\frac12}{ y-1}$ ?

Comment: @gary. Any idea to get a good approximation ? I am totally stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, $f(x)\sim\frac12x$ is very nearly linear. For large $x$ this makes secant lines very cheap and accurate approximations, so simply take two starting points and you should get approximations that work as well as Newton's method without the baggage of computing the derivative.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bZExb4MwEIV3fsU1SJFtAthOhioS3TtUqpQxMCQNBAQxEXFaV5Tfnp7tZKhUCcHdvQ/e8zFc99@3TkEWv4CB8W2n66Trj8TQKQg6Jc8NZNCprWRWWq/fX4sgqB54AKgZT5gCu6HU10GBYUQyVGJBU7JixJcUIvBzxmRMlpGt0YHaUeTLlDw/cIRoMN2qvnd2rbMLYVN@7JSGU6nr/oATvAzHCJK1ECOV2jAtE4mwgYz4T5JWOl/1BWabvvts1BGqfkAig3Bsp3WucqVy/ZPrXJ@aQ664a8LR8GnmPXFlwPH5VTddaRM8ZdZsPsd7sttfbC8SnlrGJlz4KEYsLIyLaONqa3hBgQExIjacYj6CM1HcFfemTxmOKsrE9DdFqe7n90yuKuI06o7hvuG4x0/hfptbIZer4vYL)

For example, with $k=1234$, letting $x_0=2k-\frac k{\ln(1.1k)}$ and $x_1=2k-\frac k{\ln(1.2k)}$ (tested values that seem to work fairly well) and using the secant method:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}n&x_n\\\hline0&2296.9277464706124\\1&2298.9667250536722\\2&2297.1863110696527\\3&2297.1863103392020\\4&2297.1863103392047\end{array}$$

Using values that start so close, solving the approximate version of $f$ with the secant method will converge in only a few iterates. This appears to take no more than 6 steps of the secant method to reach 15 digits accurate.

Comment: Sorry but I do not want to compute. I look for the best approximation of the solution. By the way, do you have ideas for a series approximation of $y$ such that $e^{-y}=\frac 1{2k}\frac{ y-\frac12}{ y-1}$ ?

Comment: Ah? Perhaps your intention was not so clear. I'll think on it later...

Comment: Sorry for that ! Numerically, using Newton, Halley or Householder methods go very quickly to the solution with $x_0=2k$ or, better, the very first terms of the series expansion given in my "answer". The funny story is that the solution of $h(x)=0$ is the solution of $e^{-y}=\frac 1{2k}\frac{ y-\frac12}{ y-1}$ with $x=e^y$. The problem is that I am unable to generate the series expansion of this generalized Lambert finction. Cheers and thanks in advance for any idea or suggestion.